# Sencha touch open select filed on button click

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a selectfield which show some filtering values in my app.. i want to show the select filed by a buttonclick. When the user click on a button i have to fires the select field values..

here is my code

```
  {
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        itemId: 'filterproperty',
                        cls:'propertylistonmlscss',
                        id:'filterproperty',
                        name: 'filterproperty',
                        autoSelect: false,
                        placeHolder:'Select',
                        //labelWidth: '40%',

                        options: [
                            {text: 'Select', value: '-1'},
                            {text: 'N', value: 'N'},
                            {text: 'S',  value: 'S'},
                            {text: 'E',  value: 'E'},
                            {text: 'W', value: 'W'},
                            {text: 'NW',  value: 'NW'},
                            {text: 'SW',  value: 'SW'},
                            {text: 'NE',  value: 'NE'},
                            {text: 'SE',  value: 'SE'}
                        ]
                    }
```

This is the button code

```
{
                        xtype:'button',
                        cls:'settingssavebutton',
                        itemId: 'settingsSaveButton',
                        id:'settingsSaveButton',
                        html:'Save',
                        docked: 'right',
                        border:0

                    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue ..thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `showPicker( )` on the selectfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method on the selectfield:

```
showPicker()
```